# Are there any known issues with putting invalid CSS characters (`@`,`:`,`!`) in the class attribute of a HTML element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, cross-browser, css-selectors

Are there any known issues with putting invalid CSS class characters (`@`,`:`,`!`) in the class attribute of a HTML element?  Like this:

```
<input type='text' class='compare id:txtSecondary'/>
<input type='text' class='compare @txtSecondary'/>
```

Comment: I'm sorry to be blunt, but nothing your wrote before "I was also thinking but maybe doing something like" makes _any_ sense to me.

Comment: yeah, I should probably read what I write before clicking 'Post'.

Comment: If you can go HTML5, use the data- attribute: http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/

Comment: @Mike if I didn't care about compatibility I could went with my first solution.

Comment: Edited the title as there is really no such thing as "CSS Class".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CSS fun fact! In section 4.1.3 of the [Syntax and Basic Data Types](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#keywords) (of CSS2) recommendation, it says...

> Identifiers can also contain escaped characters and any ISO 10646 character as a numeric code (see next item). For instance, the identifier "B&W?" may be written as "B\&W\?" or "B\26 W\3F".

So you can include special characters in your CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .\@user { /* valid! */
        color:red;
    }
</style>
```

Additionally, the `class` attribute [is a cdata-list](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2) which basically means "[any text except new lines and multiple spaces](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-cdata)".

So you can include something like this in your markup:

```
<div class="@user">
    This is an @user
</div>
```

Your problem isn't so much the `@` or the `:` characters, but those spaces   you've tossed in. (since in the `class` attribute spaces mean something special: "[Multiple class names must be separated by white space characters.](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2)")

Comment: interesting. The spaces are there intentionally and you can have multiple classes delimited with spaces.

Comment: ... and to my knowledge, this is implemented in most browsers.

Comment: +1 I **knew** the backslash would have some actual use in CSS other than as an IE hack.

Answer (score 2):

A simpler solution would be to split it with a dash `-` or an underscore `_`, which are both valid in CSS class names.

```
<input id='txtPrimary' type='text' class='compare id-txtSecondary'/>
<input id='txtSecondary' type='text' />

<input id='txtPrimary' type='text' class='compare id_txtSecondary'/>
<input id='txtSecondary' type='text' />
```